# override command + tab to control + tab to switch browser tabs in macOS Monterey using Karabiner Elements

Tags: macos, keyboard, monterey, keybindings, karabiner

I am using a Macbook Air M2 with macOS Monterey. I am trying to get the keyboard bindings to better/more mimic Windows 10.

The laptop keyboard is like this:

```
{fn/globe} {control} {option} {command}
```

I have swapped modifier keys from `System Preferences`.

[image]

With the above change, the keyboard buttons are like this:

```
{command} {fn/globe} {control} {option}
```

This gets me most of the way there. What is left is being able to switch tabs in Edge/Chrome. The default is `control + tab` but I want it to be `{command} tab`.

I can't set an application specific keyboard shortcut using `{command} tab` because it is used by the macOS application switcher (which I don't use/need).

So I say https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#swap-command-tab-with-control-tab for Karabiner but it does not seem to be working.

There must be a way to override the behavior so I can get `[the left most button] + tab` to switch browser tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bettertouchtool.

[image]

[image]

This will overwrite the default macOS app switcher key shortcut, and you can use the command+tab shortcut for whatever you want in the case I use it for Select Next Tab in the browser.